# How to authorize to CRaSH using ssh and key

Tags: java, spring, ssh, crash

There is a library called [CRaSH](http://www.crashub.org/), that was integrated in spring boot. The docs says, that in order to connect with ssh using key, you must add 2 lines of code in config ([link](http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_key_authentication)) and write path to a pem key

So, I added those lines, like:

```
shell.auth=key
shell.auth.key.path=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When I try to connect, it says permission denied (public key)
When I change id_rsa to id_rsa.pub it crashes on startup with exception. Maybe because it's not pem key
So, I tried to convert it

```
openssl req -x509 -key id_rsa -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out id_rsa.pem
```

it results to: Key type org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder not supported
On windows with keys generated by puttygen the picture is almost the same
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This might be quite late, but this setup helps me to connect with ssh and key to a crash shell (version 1.3.1):

- I convert my openssh/putty key to pem

  openssl rsa -in authorized.rsa -outform pem -pubout > authorized.pem
- Then I configured crash via spring:

  ```
  <bean class="org.crsh.spring.SpringWebBootstrap">
  <property name="config">
      <props>
          <prop key="crash.auth">key</prop>
          <prop key="crash.auth.key.path">WEB-INF/sshd/authorized.pem</prop>
          <!-- ... -->
      </props>
  </property>
  ```

After starting my server it is possible to connect with putty:

```
plink -i authorized.ppk -P 12345 -ssh admin@localhost
```