# Crash shell unable to connect by ssh

Tags: java, tomcat, ssh

I have a standalone Tomcat application with [CRaSH](https://www.crashub.org/) shell library embedded.
I can successfully connect to the application via telnet but I am struggling with ssh.

Here is my crash.properties config :

```
# Key authentication
crash.auth=key
crash.auth.key.path=/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/id_rsa.pem

# SSH configuration
crash.ssh.port=2000
```

I have generated a ssh keypair via ssh-keygen, then I created a pem file via `openssl rsa -in id_rsa -outform pem -pubout > id_rsa.pem` command.

Whatever the ssh key used, I have the error when I try to connect via `ssh -i /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/id_rsa -p 2000 myserver.example.com` command :

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44263518/856672) but without success. I have also tried to put the id_rsa.pem key in my war /WEB-INF/sshd folder. Same result.

Any clue ?

Comment: you probably need to also give that ssh command a port number.  SSH defaults to 22, so you need to tell it to use port 2000.  try something like `ssh -i /path/to/private/key myserver.example.com:2000`

Comment: sorry forgot to mention it in my ssh command : i use -p 2000 and same result.

Comment: Assuming you haven't gotten this working already, it might be helpful to attempt the ssh with verbose mode enabled (add -v arguments to the command line) so you can get some more information about why it thinks it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging, I notice that `org.crsh.auth.KeyAuthenticationPlugin` was comparing the authorized key and the key given at login, and they were identical but the method `authenticate` was always returning false (bad authentication). After fixing the bug, I realized that it was already declared [here](https://jira.exoplatform.org/browse/CRASH-248) and a pull request was available the [same](https://github.com/crashub/crash/pull/104/commits/8af99f0aeffd953846e248b0db4540764ddd576d) way.